# The word for the share of rows that has a value in a certain column

Tags: nouns, translation

In statistics, is there a word for the share of data items that has a value for a certain property? Or in spreadsheet terms, the share of rows that have a value in a certain column?

In Dutch, there is the word "vulgraad" (lit. "filling rate") that means just that but we find it hard to come up with a proper English translation. "Percent non-empty" is the best we came up with yet, but we feel that there has to be a noun like in Dutch.

As an example, given a table of people:

```
First name        Middle name      Last name
--------------------------------------------
Theodore                           Roosevelt
Eddy              Van              Halen
Peter                              Stuyvesant
Rutger                             Hauer
```

one could say that the middle name field has a *vulgraad* of 25%.

Comment: I strongly suspect such a word does not exist.

Comment: I agree that a word for this almost certainly doesn't exist. However, I think that if you are in an environment where you could develop a consensus among the people you are dealing with, you could probably get the term "fill rate" to stick (not "*filling* rate", which doesn't feel native enough). New terms in a language have to start somewhere, and why not with you? ;)

Answer (score 4):

I would say that the "Middle name" column is 25% populated.

Answer (score 1):

It's fill factor.
If later you want to know the counts (or just general idea) of all the repeated data values in a column, it is called value spread.

Comment: These terms by the way are the official terms in database talk.